# How to expand the axes of a plot with multiple points in Scilab?

Tags: matlab, plot, point, scilab

I am using Scilab 5.5.2. to plot multiple points. That's my script trying to plot 4 points in 2D:

```
u = [1,2;2,1;3,1;4,5;5,1]

clf; plot(u,"*r")
```

The points I am trying to plot in 2D are (1,2), (2,1), (3,1) and (5,1).

I am using "u" as vector to store the coordinates. This script generates this image:

[image]

I would like to expand the x axis and the y axis in order to have an "usual" graph. I tried doing that with this:

```
x=[0:10]

u = [1,2;2,1;3,1;4,5;5,1]

clf; plot(x,u,"*r")
```

However, I get this error message:

```
WARNING: Transposing row vector X to get compatible dimensions
 !--error 10000 
plot: Wrong size for input arguments #2 and #3: Incompatible dimensions.
at line     147 of function checkXYPair called by :  
at line     236 of function plot called by :  
clf; plot(x,u,"*r")
at line       9 of exec file called by :    
exec('poole-exemple.sci')
```

What's more, there is something weird with my plot. My script generates points that I do not want. If you look at the image, you will see a (4,4) or a (1,1) point on the plot. I do not want this and I don't know why this happens.

Does anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Data bounds

You want to change the data bounds, which is one of [many axes properties](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/axes_properties.html) accessible after executing `gca`, "get current axes". Like this:

```
plot(u(:,1), u(:, 2), "*r" )
a = gca()
a.data_bounds = [0 0; 10 7]
```

The format of data_bounds property is [xmin, ymin; xmax, ymax].

And here is a better way to set it, based on the data:

```
a.data_bounds = [min(u, 'r') - 1; max(u, 'r') + 1]
```

This sets the minimum bound to the smallest data value - 1, and maximum to the largest value + 1.

#### Incorrect points

The [documentation](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/plot.html) explains that the parameters of `plot` command are: vector of x values and vector of y values: separately, not in one matrix. With your data it should be

```
plot(u(:,1), u(:, 2), "*r" )
```

not `plot(u, "*r")`.

Comment: Thanks @Gerry. However, a problem keeps happening. When I plot using your commands I still get points like (3,3) . There is no (3,3) in u = [1,2;2,1;3,1;4,5;5,1] . How can I fix this?

Comment: Does not happen for me. Did you clear out the old figure with clf?

Comment: Yeah, the problem was exactly that... Do you think it is a good idea to put clf in my script? Like on the line before the plot() command? Is it a good practice?

Comment: Yes, people usually put it at the beginning of script, to erase old plots.